# why am i getting error message when using auth::attempt in laravel?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

here is the code i am using :

```
if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>Input::get('email'),'password'=>Input::get('password')])) return Response::json('wellcome',404);
```

and here is the error message :
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Controller method not found.

and here is the route :

```
Route::get('login','login@showLogin');
Route::post('login','login@doLogin');
Route::get('logout','login@logout');
```

the logout and show login works , the login works as well except for the part where i use attempt!!!! , when i comment out the line where Auth::attempt i written , no error message get displayed !!!!

Comment: `Auth::attempt()` code seems fine. May be the fault lie somewhere else. Could you post the complete code of the `doLogin` function?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are returning an [status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) of 404, which stands for **Not Found**.

Change this:

`return Response::json('wellcome', 404);`

to this:

`return Response::json('wellcome', 200);`

and see what happens. You can ommit the `200` parameter if you want, since it's the default value. Also keep in mind that in order to return a JSON object, you should use an array as first parameter:

`return Response::json(['foo' => 'bar']);`